# Unable to Read filename from CSV file and find it in another folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, google-colaboratory

I need to traverse entries of a CSV file that consists of the following structure:

**Img_File |  Class**

---

img1.png |

img2.png |

...

The first column contains filenames and the other column **Class** is empty. All these files are saved in a folder in path **PATH**. I need to

- traverse through each filename in the CSV file
- access the file from the location PATH
- pass it to a model and make predictions (predict class)
- save the predicted class to the other column in the row of the image being processed.

I have managed to make the predictions for a image, but I am unable to do the same for the given files mentioned in the CSV file. How should I proceed?

Here is the link to the notebook for reproducing the problem: [LINK](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1198tG2EUw-GyePuUlhZFGOCN0GzGUkzg)

P.S: There may be more than 1 issues with my code.

Comment: What did you try, and what error did you encounter? Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces your issue?

Comment: @BobSmith i have added the notebook. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it some time and got it right:

> traverse through each filename in the CSV file

`import pandas as pd
 dff = pd.read_csv(path, index_col="Column_with_all_filenames")`

> access the file from the location PATH

`for img_name, Class in dff.iterrows():
  if(".png" in img_name): #Check is the name is that of a PNG file 
    if(find(img_name, path) ):   #Check if the file was found in the path
      im=test_img_dir+'/'+img_name    #Modify the path of the 
      print(im)
      im = image.imread(im)
      #Make Predictions`

> save the predicted class to the other column in the row of the image

```
      #Create a list of the [filename--Prediction]
      listof_rows.append([file_name, prediction])

      #After all the files have been processed...
      df=pd.DataFrame(listof_rows, columns=['Image_File', 'Class'])
      df.to_csv('Result1.csv', index=False)
```